# child div hide border from parent

Tags: css

I have a menu and this menu has a div on the top.

the problem is, I want to hide the border in front of this child div. I don't want to separete divs, I need #menu2top to be inside #menu2.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/t9ag9yxy/1/

```css
#menu2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 102;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu2top {
  height: 45px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, .2);
  z-index: 103;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu2>

  <div id=menu2top></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by changing `overflow-y` to `visible`, and the `width` of `#menu2top` to `201px`. Also note, though, that with a background opacity of `0.2` on `#menu2top`, the border is going to mostly show through anyway. You may want to make that not transparent, depending on what your goal is. :)

Answer (score 1):

you may use a background-image or gradient :

```css
#menu2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 102;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  background:linear-gradient(black,black)no-repeat right 45px;
  background-size:1px 100% ;
}
#menu2top {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, .2);
  z-index: 103;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu2>

  <div id=menu2top></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo `after` to accomplish that

```css
#menu2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 102;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}
#menu2:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 45px;
}

#menu2top {
  height: 45px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, .2);
  z-index: 103;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu2>

  <div id=menu2top></div>

</div>
```